# How to retrieve xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation from XML with lxml?

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml

I am trying to validate XML based on `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`.

I researched this question but it doesn't seem any available solutions for it.

My XML file looks this way:

```
<shiporder orderid="889923"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="shiporder.xsd">
  <orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>
  <shipto>
    <name>Ola Nordmann</name>
    <address>Langgt 23</address>
    <city>4000 Stavanger</city>
    <country>Norway</country>
  </shipto>
  <item>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <note>Special Edition</note>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>10.90</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>9.90</price>
  </item>
</shiporder>
```

I took it from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/XML/schema_example.asp)

This is what I get when parse and take attrib from root
`{'{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation': 'shiporder.xsd'}`

How can I do it with `lxml` in Python? I looked on other parsers but so far no idea how to do it.

Comment: In the XML document, the `xsi` prefix is associated with the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` namespace URI. A prefix by itself does not identify a namespace (the prefix is just an arbitrary shorthand). The full name of the attribute is `{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation` (the syntax is called Clark notation), and that is what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @mzjn for pointing out about Clark notation.

The solution I came up with is:

```
from lxml import etree

...

it = etree.fromstring(xml)
# We need to go through all keys since they can be in
# Clark notation and have URL with brackets as a prefix
for attr in it.attrib:
    if 'noNamespaceSchemaLocation' in attr:
        xsd = it.attrib.get(attr)
        break

...

# Do validations based on XSD URL value
```